# iOS core motion drifts in cars, trains, flights

Tags: ios, core-motion

I get feedback from my users, that "from time to time" my Game-App has a bug were the ship gets completely uncontrollable. After investigating into this, it looks like the attitude, reported by CoreMotion drift away very fast (below a second) and it does that suddenly. You can play for up to five minutes, then it happens suddenly that the ship moves to one of the screen borders and does not move away from that point any more.

**My question**: Has anybody made the same experience with CoreMotion attitude and what are your ways or ideas to get control over this sudden, massive drifts?

The code I'm using to get the attitude in the `update()` of SpriteKit is:

```
if let motion = motionManager.deviceMotion {
    let x = CGFloat(motion.attitude.yaw - basePosition.x)
    let y = CGFloat(motion.attitude.roll - basePosition.y)
    ship.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(X_SENSITITVITY * x, Y_SENSITITVITY * y))
}
```

where `basePosition`, `X_SENSITITVITY`, `Y_SENSITITVITY` are constant values in the game.
`motionManager` is defined by `private var motionManager = CMMotionManager()` at the top of the class.

As far as I understand the documentation, `deviceMotion` uses a combination of gravity and attitude measure to minimise the long term drift somehow.

Maybe also important to notice: When the Game runs in a silent environment without the vibrations of cars etc,  it works perfectly fine.
I would like to have people to play my game whenever they need a rest - like on long train rides or flights - or kids in the backseat of the car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I've found a way to handle this. And as I see a number of views on this question there might be some interest in the answer and some people dealing with the same issue.

From my understanding, there're two things you can rely on:

1. The change of devices in motion. Specifically `CMDeviceMotion.rotationRate`
2. The attitude of a device towards earth. Specifically `CMDeviceMotion.gravity`

It looks like the first uses changes in current position by reading some kind of current forces. This is a current value and there's no need to sum up the values - and therefore no errors are summed up.

The second one (gravity) measures the current forces against earth. Again: current values, no sum up, no sum up of errors, no drift.

Anything else, especially `CMDeviceMotion.attitude`, takes measures and adds them up. Leading to adding up the small errors in each measure, leading to a drift in the result.
I've tried to use rotation rate and calculate the attitude myself by adding up. Well, Apple is not perfect in doing that, but way better then any of my solutions :-)

Talk is cheap. Where's the code? Here it is. This method is called during `update()` in SpriteKit (for every frame)

```
private func update(ship: SKSpriteNode) {
    // Orientation can be landscape left or right
    let orientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft ? -1.0 : 1.0

    // Get rotation rate
    let x = orientation*motionManager.deviceMotion.rotationRate.x
    let y = orientation*motionManager.deviceMotion.rotationRate.y

    // If user tilts device very slow it does not affect the ship
    let xf = CGFloat(abs(x) >= X_RESPONSIVNESS ? X_SENSITITVITY*x : 0.0)
    let yf = CGFloat(abs(y) >= Y_RESPONSIVNESS ? Y_SENSITITVITY*y : 0.0)

    // Apply as impulse
    ship.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(xf, yf))
}
```

As my game is more about "how does the user tilt the device to let me know where you want the ship go to" I simply used `rotationRate` to measure this and apply it as impulse. As an add-on you can rotate the device which means that what was a rotation towards the top of the screen is actually a rotation to the bottom after rotation. So I have to invert the impulse when the device is rotated.

You can now play the game in any direction. Landscape left, Landscape right, overhead, in a vibrating environment like cars or trains. It works like a charm. I'm even looking forward to a 2.5 hours flight next Saturday...

Comment: Does anyone know how to calculate rotationMatrix from rotationRate? I'm having similar issue in my app, but I need rotationMatrix. Maybe if I could get it from rotationRate, problem would also disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the same drift problem. I compared the CMDeviceMotion's attitude with the CLLocation's magneticHeading. Therefor, I walked 10 times around a small table and put the device after every round on the exact same place.

I figured out, that the DeviceMotion's attitude drifts around 30 degrees every round. Thus, after 10 rounds the attitude is around 300 degrees off.
According to Apple's WWDC 2012 talk "Session 524: Understanding core motion" the used sensor fusion depends on the specified reference frame. Phil Adam mentions, that the sensor fusion algorithm also uses the magnetometer if the xArbitraryCorrected reference frame is specified. I did the same test with xArbitrary, xArbitraryCorrected and xMagneticNorth, but there is no difference. The compass's uncertainty is around 2 - 3 degree (with a heading filter of 1.0 degree).

Maybe it's a bug, I don't know. But I expected at least a difference between xArbitrary and xArbitraryCorrected.

Comment: Yes it looks like there're some promises in the docs and videos which are just make no real difference. I have changed my algorithm in the meantime from a pure attitude approach towards an approach where I measure just changes in orientation (specifically rotationRate) This works fine as I don't need the absolute position. I'll share the code.